# FTP Upload in Release Pipeline fails with FTPError: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ftp

I have created a Release Pipeline in Azure Devops that first archives two files and then tries to upload those zip files to an FTP server.

The archiving works fine, however the upload task always fails. I receive the following console output:

```
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9716469Z ##[section]Starting: FTP Upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9792841Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9792892Z Task         : FTP upload
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9792921Z Description  : Upload files using FTP
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9792964Z Version      : 2.157.0
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9792992Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9793020Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload
2020-02-13T10:28:03.9793049Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-13T10:28:04.9536900Z connecting to: mydomain.com:21
2020-02-13T10:28:05.1325089Z ##[error]FTPError: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
2020-02-13T10:28:05.1333616Z ##[error]Ftp Upload failed
2020-02-13T10:28:31.5036758Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2020-02-13T10:28:31.5040435Z ##[section]Finishing: FTP Upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Here is my YAML:

```
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftp://mydomain.com'
    username: usr
    password: pwd
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    remoteDirectory: '/files/upload-Test/'
    trustSSL: true
```

I also tried to connect to a different SFTP server, but I received similar results: `FTPError: 550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel`

Do you have any suggestions what I could try in order to make this work?

**EDIT: Now with Debug output:**

```
expanding braces
pattern: 'D:/a/r1/a/$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**'
applying include pattern against original list
1 matches
1 final results
Found total matches: 1
adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\FILENAME.zip
connecting to: domain.com:21
Connected to MY-IP
< 220 Speak friend, and enter
Login security: No encryption
> USER usr
< 331 FTP login okay, send password.
> PASS ###
< 230 User logged in, proceed.
> TYPE I
< 200 Using BINARY mode to transfer data.
> STRU F
< 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
FTPError: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]FTPError: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
task result: Failed
Ftp Upload failed
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Ftp Upload failed
Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Ftp Upload failed
```

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , there is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which could be the reason of this error.

The shortage of ATs is causing high CPU on the ATs, resulting in slow and failed **commands** across Boards, Repos, Pipelines, and Test Plans.

[image]

If you want to know more detailed information, please refer to this [report](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/175966778).The issue is now fully mitigated.

Comment: I guess you suggested that the FTP upload should then be working now? I just redeployed the pipeline and received the same result. Is there a possibility to turn on more diagnostics, verbose output, or something similar?

Comment: You can set `system.debug= true` to get more detailed log

Comment: do you have any other idea what I could try?

Comment: You can try to run with private agent to see if the same result.